# Removing MySQL Records From Table by Sales Amount

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large table of businesses. There is a field with the sales of each company and I want to remove every record with sales that are over 2000000, but records are VARCHAR and have commas in them like this 2,000,000

Will something like this work?

```
DELETE FROM `tablename` WHERE `sales` > 2,000,000
```

Comment: What data type is the sales column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the comma and force a number conversion

```
DELETE FROM `tablename` 
WHERE replace(sales, ',', '') * 1 > 2000000
```

#### BTW it would be better to change the data type of the  `sales` column to a numberic one.

Answer (score 0):

```
    delete from table1 where replace( replace(sales, ',', ''), '"', '' ) >=200000
```

Here is [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2b65c/1)

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you have commas in your number values, do you mean that you store numbers in your DB as VARCHAR type? Or do you store sales values in a field of numeric type and then just apply format with a FORMAT() function to add the commas?

If you store numbers as VARCHAR, your example query will not work, but if you store those values as numeric type, you can just ignore commas and use

```
DELETE FROM `tablename` WHERE `sales` > 2000000
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, they are VARCHAR, I just edited the question to reference that.